# Run single command as other user; restrictions on sudo

Tags: sudo, su

I'm working on a machine where I don't have root, but there is a list of allowed `sudo` commands. One of these commands is `/bin/su - foouser`. So I can type `sudo su - foouser`, and I get an interactive shell as foouser. Then I can run some stuff as `foouser`.

The problem is that `foouser` is a shared user/shell that is used for spawning certain important production processes. I can't easily customize it or set it up the way I want. And I shouldn't be working in it consistently which splits up my terminals, and command history between ones where I'm logged in as myself and ones where I'm `foouser`.

What I'd really like to do is to have a way to run a single command as `foouser`, have it block, print out stdout and stderr to my shell as a command usually would, and then return with me still logged in as myself (and not `foouser`). This could e.g. be encapsulated in a script so that `as_foo bar` runs the command `bar`, as `foouser`, prints stdout and stderr, returns return code of `bar`, and then puts me back in my shell.

I can ask the sys admins to change permissions. For example, they could add `bar` to the sudo list, and then I could use (I think) `su -c` to run bar in the fashion I described. But then if the next day I want to run `bar2`, I have to talk to them again.

Is there any way out of this dilemna? It seems rather silly because I obviously can become `foouser` and run as many commands as I want, so there is no difference in terms of security that I can see. Just can't find any obvious convenient way to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo su - foouser <command>` requires you to have at least limited root access to run `su - foouser <command>` as root.

`sudo -u foouser <command>` can do what you want in one step. But it requires that the sysadmin has granted you `sudo` access to `foouser` account in this way:

```
ignacio ALL=(foouser) ALL
```

instead of this way:

```
ignacio ALL=(root) su - foouser
```

Configuring `sudo` in this way will allow you to define e.g. an alias like you envisioned:

```
as_foo='sudo -u foouser'
```

And by avoiding the `su -`, you may be able to keep using your own customizations: using `sudo` in this way changes just the user identity but keeps `HOME` at its previous value, reading any shell startup scripts and other customizations from **your** home directory instead of `foouser`'s.

(Of course, those scripts must then be readable by that other user too, and any shared scripts you might run had better refer to `foouser`'s home directory explicitly as `/home/foouser` instead of just `$HOME`.)

However, there are some `sudo` settings that can prevent that solution from working: if the `always_set_home` sudo option is set in the sudoers file, or if `env_reset` option is set without adding `HOME` to the `env_keep` list, `HOME` will be reset anyway. In such a situation, try adding the `-E` option to `sudo` command to explicitly request keeping your environment.

And when you really want to run something as `foouser` with the environment set exactly as it is when logged in as `foouser` (i.e. the equivalent of `sudo su - foouser`), add the `-i` option to specifically request that. So `sudo -i -u foouser` is an 100% accurate replacement of `sudo su - foouser`.

If you find some system with such an ancient version of `sudo` that it does not have the `-i` option, use the `-H` option with sudo instead: it's not a perfect replacement, but it might be enough. Such an old version of `sudo` will quite likely have some security-sensitive known bugs too, so it would be worthwhile to update it anyway.

You can use `sudo -l` as yourself to see exactly how your sudo access is defined and which sudo options (aka Defaults entries) are in effect for you.

Comment: This looks very promising, I'll accept as soon as I'm able to test and it works!

Answer (score -1):

Pass additional arguments to `su`.

```
sudo su - foouser sh -c 'echo $USER'
```